# Couldn't find ContentTemplate with 'id'=batch_stats

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route that looks like this:

```
get 'content_templates/batch_stats', to: 'content_templates#batch_stats', as: 'batch_stats'
```

when I invoke the following helper:

```
<%= link_to 'Statistics', batch_stats_path %>
```

I expect to go to the batch_stats action of content_templates controller.

```
  def batch_stats
    puts "Are we ever getting here??"
    ...
```

Unfortunately the action is never triggered. Rails blows up before it even gets to the controller:

```
  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find ContentTemplate with 'id'=batch_stats:
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:320:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:420:in `find_one'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:404:in `find_with_ids'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:68:in `find'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/model_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:20:in `find'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:116:in `find_resource'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:68:in `load_resource_instance'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
  cancancan (1.9.2) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
  ...
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Make sure that you restart your server for new routes

Comment: I did have server restarted. Even after restart, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had two kinds of routes:

```
  resources :content_templates do
    get :show_template, on: :member
  end

  get 'content_templates/batch_stats', to: 'content_templates#batch_stats', as: 'batch_stats'
```

I got rid of the second one and just added a collection to first one:

```
  resources :content_templates do
    get :show_template, on: :member
    get :batch_stats, on: :collection
  end
```

And now it no longer looks for a member id.